# Android Fragment lifecycle issue on change orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have an Activity which use a Viewpager.Viewpager has a few Fragments and of course Fragments are prepared by a FragmentPagerAdapter.Let me give an example :

Here is my activity:

```
public class SampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private ViewPager viewpager;
private SampleFragmentAdapter sample_fragment_adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_layout);
    viewpager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.sample_pager);
    sample_fragment_adapter = new SampleFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),this);
    viewpager.setAdapter(sample_fragment_adapter);
}
```

FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class SampleFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

 private Context context;
 private int fCount;
 private SampleFragment[] fragment_list;

    public SampleFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm,Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context=context;
        fragment_list=new SampleFragment[8];
        fCount=fragment_list.length;
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            fragment_list[i]=new SampleFragment();
            fragment_list[i].setList(getList());
        }
    }
}

@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragment_list[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fCount;
    }

public void getList(){

        //here , an arraylist which is not null is returned
        //this arraylist includes data using by listview in fragment
}
```

And finally my Fragment class (Fragment includes a listview):

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

private View view;
private ListView sample_list_view;
private LessonListAdapter sample_list_adapter;
private ArrayList<Sample> sample_list;

public void setList(ArrayList<Sample> sample_list){
    this.sample_list=sample_list;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_list_layout, container, false);
     sample_list_view=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.sample_list_view);
     sample_list_adapter=new SampleListAdapter(getActivity(),sample_list);
     sample_list.setAdapter(sample_list_adapter);
     return view;
}
```

My problem : When activity starts on any orientation , it works perfectly.But when I change orientation , I guess activity starts again and onCreateView method in SampleFragment is called before setList() method.So null arraylist goes to sample_list_adapter but Fragment view can not prepared untill arraylist is ready.I guess this is lifecycle problem of Fragment.How can solve ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: why not set the list in `onCreateView()`

Comment: How can I pass list to onCreateView(), Give me an example as code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a final `List`:

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

private View view;
private ListView sample_list_view;
private LessonListAdapter sample_list_adapter;
private final ArrayList<Sample> sample_list = new ArrayList<Sample>();

public void setList(ArrayList<Sample> sample_list){
    this.sample_list.clear();
    this.sample_list.addAll(sample_list);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_list_layout, container, false);
     sample_list_view=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.sample_list_view);
     sample_list_adapter=new LessonListAdapter(getActivity(),sample_list);
     sample_list.setAdapter(sample_list_adapter);
     return view;
}
```

This will change the list inside the adapter, not replacing the list after setting the empty list to the adapter.

Make sure, you save the ArrayList across instances:

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    private final ArrayList<Sample> sample_list = new ArrayList<Sample>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        if (state != null) {
            setList((private final ArrayList<Sample> sample_list = new ArrayList<Sample>();)state.getSerializable("list");
        }
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState();
        state.putSerializable("list", sample_list);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I change orientation , list is not null of course , but it has no element.So after change orientation , any list item does not appear in fragment

Comment: Yeah maybe it's not null, but my answer will fight it anyway. You may need to save the ArrayList in `onSaveState(Bundle state)` retrieve it later in `onCreate(Bundle state)`

Comment: How can I pass arraylist via bundle , can you give me an example as code

Comment: See above. But make sure Sample implements `Serializable`.

Comment: right. But the objects need to implement serializable. so only basic types and serializables are allowed. you can mark fields as transient to exclude it from serialization.

Comment: Ok thanks for advice , I will try soon and I will give feedback